# Sending data to another computer in local network

Tags: c++, networking

I'm new to this part! Could you please post some tutorials or whatever that will help me with that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use: [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

It teaches you a lot about Networking via sockets etc.